# Why do I get "no remote for the current branch" after cloning a repository and running merge?

Tags: git

I have an issue while trying to merge my local repository with a remote repository. I am currently following an exercise and have made the following steps:

1. Forked the repository from GitHub to a personal account
2. Cloned the repository using HTTPS and then the command: git clone https://github.com/Cyber-surf/gitactivity.git
3. Checked file structure and everything seems intact including .git folder. Usining the command: ls -la
4. Created a new branch with the command: git branch test
5. Switched to the new branch with the command: git checkout test
6. Created a new file using the command: touch test.txt
7. Added the file with the command: git add test.txt
8. Commit with the command: git commit -m "added test.txt"
9. Ran fetch with the command: git fetch - but no results from command (so I presume it was successful)
10. Ran merge with the command: git merge - fatal: no remote for the current branch.

As I'm a beginner I don't want to mess with things I don't really understand yet.

Comment: Hi! Can you include the commands you ran? There are many options for each step you describe, meaning there are many ways you can do those steps. Redact URLs and other info specific to your case if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've just edited my original post, I hope it's clear.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I think you misunderstand when the merge command is meant to be used. So try to explain what you are trying to do without using the work "merge". Do you want to push your commit to the remote so that it is visible on GitHub? If so, try `git push`

Comment: I am following an exercise and I was just trying to furfill each step with no errors. Yes, I believe what I am trying to do is update my remote repository with the new commit from my local repository. I could try push as it's a combination of fetch and merge, but if that works then I've skipped the step of using merge and wouldn't really understand why it didn't work. Is there a reason push would work over merge?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Your branch `test` has no *upstream* set.  This means `git merge` needs at least one more argument.  You can:

- provide an upstream setting, and/or
- provide the additional argument(s)

to fix this.  (But there's nothing to *do*, at least not yet, so this doesn't really matter anyway.)

## Long

> I have an issue while trying to merge my local repository with a remote repository. I am currently following an exercise and have made the following steps ... As I'm a beginner I don't want to mess with things I don't really understand yet.

Let's go through the various steps one by one.  There's really only one "error" here (and it's quite minor).  And, since this *is* just an exercise, don't worry about breaking anything, you can just remove the entire clone and start over!  (I did that a lot when I started with Git, but that was 15 or so years ago at this point.  After a while you get the hang of it and this stops happening.)

> 1. Forked the repository from GitHub to a personal account

Note that this operation happens purely *on* GitHub.  A GitHub "fork" is GitHub's way of encouraging you to do a GitHub-side, modified `git clone`: this adds features for you (which you may or may not find valuable yourself, and if you do, this encourages you to stick with GitHub which adds value to *their* existence and hence you both profit).  It also sets things up on *their* side so that they don't need as much disk space.  So it's a three-way win (with two of those *their* wins and one yours).

> 2. Cloned the repository using HTTPS and then the command: git clone https://github.com/Cyber-surf/gitactivity.git

Cloning a repository makes a copy of it.  When you copy a repository, you copy *all the commits* (or sometimes a bit fewer than all), and usually, *none of the branches*.  Then, just before your `git clone` finishes, your Git makes *one* branch in your new clone.  This is fine because Git doesn't actually require branches: Git is really all about *commits*.

Git isn't about files, and isn't about branches, it's just about *commits*.  We (humans) use branch names *because* the commit ID numbers are big ugly random-looking horrible things that no human can deal with.  The names—`main` or `master`, for instance—simply help us (and Git) find the *commit* we care about.

Each commit—besides being apparently-randomly-numbered so that Git can find it by number—stores two things: a *full snapshot of every file*, and some *metadata*, which holds information about the commit itself.  The full snapshot holds the files in a special, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* format.

This de-duplication takes care of the first obvious objection to storing every file every time: most of the time, a *new* commit mostly re-uses most of the files from the immediate previous commit.  If Git didn't de-duplicate files, your repository would grow immensely fat very quickly, and the whole system would bog down and eat all your disk space.  But Git *does* de-duplicate (and compress) the files, so if you wind up making a commit that exactly matches some earlier commit—this can happen in a number of ways—the files literally take *no space at all*.  Only *changes* take space, and even then, Git has tricks that minimize this (for ordinary text files: they don't work well for compressed binary files like JPG images).

Anyway, since the files *are* compressed and Git-ified—and in fact, read-only: all parts of *every* commit are 100% read-only—they're literally unusable for getting any actual work done.  Your computer programs need files they can read, and only Git can read these files; and your computer programs need files they can *write* as well.  So you don't work on or with these internally-stored files that are *in* the commits.  You work, instead, on files that Git *copies out of the commits*, into your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

The files in your working tree are ordinary everyday files.  All your normal computer programs work on these files.  But these files *are not in Git at all*.  They simply came *out of Git*, and later, you'll use them to build new, compressed, Git-ified, de-duplicated files that will go in future commits.  It's important to keep in mind though that the *working* files are *outside the repository*, in your work-tree.  The *repository* is in the hidden `.git` folder at the top level of your work-tree.

The *metadata* stored in each commit is also very important to Git itself.  It may be less important to you, depending on what you're doing.  We'll skip right over this part to keep this answer short (well, short for *me*).

> 3. Checked file structure and everything seems intact including .git folder. Using the command: ls -la

The `ls` command inspects your *working tree*, where Git has copied out the files from the latest commit on whatever branch name you're using.  Remember that this is *your* branch name: your Git software made it, in your repository, from a branch name your Git saw in the other Git repository that you cloned.

Your `git clone` command left out the `-b` option (which is a normal thing to do!).  If you *had* used `-b`, you would have told your Git which name you wanted it to make at the end of the clone operation, but without it, your Git software asks their (GitHub's) software what branch name *they* recommend.  That's usually `main` these days (and in the old days, `master`).  So that will be the *name* your Git created.

That name selects some particular commit.  The commit your `main`—I'll just *assume* `main` here now—selects is the *same commit* that *their* (GitHub's) repository's `main` selects.  Here's a not-secret "secret" that beginners often miss:

- `git clone` copies all their commits and *none of their branch names*, but
- `git clone` reads *all of their branch names* and *changes them* into what I call *remote-tracking names*.  Your Git then stores these names in your repository.

Git calls these things *remote-tracking branch names*, but the word *branch* here seems a bit pointless, and the word "branch" is badly overloaded in Git.  I find that leaving it out—saying that these are *remote-tracking names*—actually works better.  So whatever *branch* names they have, in their (GitHub's) clone, your Git now has *remote-tracking names* instead.

I mentioned earlier that a GitHub "fork" is a GitHub-side, slightly-modified clone.  The big visible modification is that when you use the <kbd>FORK</kbd> button on GitHub, they not only copy all the commits, they also copy all the branch names.  So your fork, on GitHub, has the same set of branch names as the repository you forked.  This is different from your local clone on your laptop, where all the branch names have become remote-tracking names.

This is important *because* you're going to find *your* commits via *your branch* names.  So it's good to keep straight which names are which.

> 4. Created a new branch with the command: git branch test

This is all fine.  It's now time now to start talking about commits, metadata, and branch names though.

I mentioned before that each commit is numbered.  If you run:

```
git log
```

your Git will spill out these numbers: they're huge and ugly and impossible to deal with, except by computer (cut-and-paste for instance), but your laptop is a computer and hence has no problem with the numbers.

The *first* number that spills out, though, will have two or more *names* that help Git—and you—*find* it.  Assuming you do this `git log` right at this point—just after you made the new name `test`—you would get (except that I made up the commit number here, yours *will* be different):

```
commit 6cc022f7696a45f5b3814d7659a7b0f16436b4bf (HEAD -> main, test, origin/main)
Author: ...
Date:   ...
...
```

The commit number is the magic that every Git everywhere will use for *this* commit: it's how two different pieces of Git software, working on two different repositories that may or may not be clones, can decide whether they *share* this particular commit.  (This hashing magic is what makes Git work.  It's vaguely akin to various cryptocurrency ideas.)  If the two Gits have the same number, they *both* have a copy of that commit.  If not, the Git that lacks the commit can get the commit from the other Git.

Anyway, inside this commit there's a full snapshot of every file (but compressed and de-duplicated), plus this metadata.  The metadata include:

- the name and email address of the commit's author, which `git log` shows here;
- the date-and-time for when the author *made* that commit, which `git log` shows;
- the same kind of stuff for the *committer*, which `git log` hides by default but you can make it show it;
- a *log message* where each author is supposed to tell you *why* they made that particular commit: not *what* they did (Git can figure that out), but *why*; and
- for Git itself, a list of hash IDs of *previous* commits.

This list-of-previous-commits is usually exactly one element long.  When it is one element long like this, we get a simple chain of commits, with each commit "pointing backwards" to its *parent*, like so:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *latest* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` contains both snapshot and metadata, and the metadata for `H` gives the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Commit `G`, too, contains both snapshot and metadata.  Git can show you what *changed* in `H` by comparing the two snapshots.  Then, having shown that (or not) in `git log`, Git can move back one hop to commit `G`.  Using the metadata in `G`, Git can show you who made it and when, and move back one hop to `F` to get its snapshot.  So now Git can diff `F`-vs-`G` to show you what *changed*, and/or move back one hop to show you the log message for `F`.  `F` of course points backwards, and so on, all the way back to the very first commit ever—which, being *first*, can't point back, and thus doesn't, allowing `git log` to stop.

So, the *names* just help Git find that last commit in the chain:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), test, origin/main
```

The `HEAD` in parentheses here—which `git log` shows as `HEAD -> main`—is just a way of showing *which branch name you're using*.  You're using the name `main` to find commit `H`, which contains a (read-only, frozen-for-all-time) snapshot of files; Git has copied the files *from* `H` to your working tree for you to work with.

> 5. Switched to the new branch with the command: git checkout test

The result of this is:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main, test (HEAD), origin/main
```

That is, we're now using the name `test` to find commit `H`, instead of using `main` to find commit `H`.

Had we found a *different* commit, Git would have had to rip out all the `H`-commit files from your working tree, and put in the other commit's files.  But since we switched *from* `H` *to* `H`, we didn't really go anywhere, and Git didn't bother pulling out and replacing the files.  (Exercise: if Git *had* done that, how would you know?)

> 6. Created a new file using the command: touch test.txt

This creates a new file in your working tree.  Git isn't aware of the existence of this file yet (barring some sort of background file-watching program anyway: Git has some of these under development for speed reasons).

> 7. Added the file with the command: git add test.txt

This informs Git that it should *copy* the new file, `test.txt`, into the internal, compressed, de-duplicated, ready-to-commit format.  The new copy goes into what Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  (I'm skipping over a lot here because this index / staging-area thing is quite crucial, but I'm trying to keep this short.  If concreteness helps, by the way, "the index" is *mostly*, though not always entirely, actually just a file named `.git/index`, which you can see if you really want to: just don't *change* it as it's full of sensitive, and binary, Git-ized cache data.  It's possible to rebuild this if you wreck it, so it's not a serious problem, but why create problems for yourself?)

> 8. Commit with the command: git commit -m "added test.txt"

This has Git build a *new* commit.  The new commit has a new unique hash ID.  The new commit has some metadata—as all commits must—and a snapshot.  Git makes the *snapshot* from whatever is in Git's index.  Git gathers the metadata from you and whatever else it has around:

- Your `user.name` setting, whatever you've set for it, is the author.
- Your `user.email` setting, whatever you've set for it, is the author's email.
- The current date-and-time is the date-and-time.
- The *current commit's hash ID* (the raw hash ID of commit `H` in our case) is the new commit's (single) *parent*.
- Any log message you like, that you supply with `-m` or an editor or whatever, is your log message.

Note that `added test.txt` is a pretty terrible log message: Git can mechanically tell you that this is what happened in the commit.  Your log messages are up to you, but it's a good idea to tell your future self *why* you did this, e.g., "added file as per exercise 2.1 of the book Dooming The Earth with Git" or something: something less obvious *about* the commit, that will tell you *why* you did that.

(Many commit messages are terrible: [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1296/))

Let's draw the new commit `I`, pointing back to existing commit `H`, and show where the various names now point:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
            \
             I   <-- test (HEAD)
```

**This is the sneaky trick that `git commit` just pulled:** the *name* `test` now points to *new commit `I`*.  New commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`, so commits up through and including `H` are still on both branches `main` and `test`, but *new* commit `I` is *only* findable by starting at `I` and working backwards, using the name `test`.

*Git, and you, find commits by starting from names and working backwards.*  They don't have to be *branch* names, but branch names are normally the "right way" to do this *because* `git commit` *automatically updates the name*.  You make a new commit, and `git commit` reads the branch name from `HEAD`—to see what you're `on branch test`, as `git status` will say—and stuffs the *new* hash ID into that name, so that `test` now points to new commit `I`.

> 9. Ran fetch with the command: git fetch - but no results from command (so I presume it was successful)

It was, yes: `git fetch` has your Git call up some other Git, the software on GitHub in this case, and connect to *their* repository.  They list out their branch names and commit hash IDs, and your Git checks to see if any of those are new commit hash IDs to *you*.

In this case, all of those were the same old hash IDs you saw last time.  Your Git says: *meh, nothing new here, goodbye!* and does absolutely nothing.  So your repository is totally unchanged.  Had they had some new commit(s), your Git would have greedily gulped them in.  Suppose there were some new commit, with a different new and random-looking hash ID, on *their* `main`.  We'll call this commit `J`, and say that it points back to existing commit `H` (note that it can't point to `I`, as only *you* have `I`).  Then you would have:

```
             J   <-- origin/main
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I   <-- test (HEAD)
```

> 10. Ran merge with the command: git merge - fatal: no remote for the current branch.

This is the only actual error.

The `git merge` command is big and complicated, and to avoid making this answer very long, we'll just touch on it lightly here.  The *idea* behind `git merge` is to *combine work*.  To do that, Git has to locate not one, not two, but *three* commits.

One of these three commits is always your current commit.  Since you're on branch `test`, which locates commit `I`, that's commit `I`.

The second of the two commits is one you name on the command line:

```
git merge a1234567
```

for instance tells Git to find a commit using `a1234567`, which is presumably an abbreviated hash ID (you can cut and paste real hash IDs from `git log` output here).  Or:

```
git merge origin/main
```

tells Git to use the name `origin/main`—your *remote-tracking* name, by which your Git remembers *their* repository's `main`—to locate commit `H` or `J` or whatever.

Once Git has these two commits, it will use the *graph*—the thing we've been drawing here—to find the *best shared commit*.  This is in many ways the most important part of a merge, because it's the *merge base* that determines what "work" Git can combine.  Had there been a commit `J`, and had you run `git merge hash-of-J` or `git merge origin/main`, Git would have worked its way backwards from commits `I` and `J` to commit `H`.  That commit *is* on both branches, and in this case, is the best such commit, so that would be the merge base, and would determine what work Git is supposed to merge.

Since there were no such commits, though, you still just have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
            \
             I   <-- test (HEAD)
```

and `git merge origin/main` would direct your Git to combine the work in `I`, your current commit, with the work from the merge base to commit `H`.  The merge base would still *be* `H`, and from `H` to `H` there *is no work done* and therefore there is nothing to combine.  So this would also fail, with a different "error" (not really an error): `Already up to date.`

There's one more special case, which Git calls a *fast-forward*, where they have some work and you don't.  Only if there is something to combine does `git merge` really have to do any real work.  We won't cover these other cases here.  Instead, we'll just mention the thing I started with.

#### Branches have optional upstreams

Each *branch name* in your repository—in this case, `main` and `test`—can have *one upstream*.  An upstream is just another name, and in most typical use cases, the upstream is a *remote-tracking name*.

Your existing `main` will have an upstream set already, and its upstream will be `origin/main`.  This is the most common setup: the upstream of branch *`B`*, for some *`B`*, is `origin/B`.  The name `origin` is the initial—and usually only—*remote* and therefore all *remote-tracking names* start with `origin/`.  Since humans are human, and like to use the *same name* in both "sides" of a Git setup like this—in our GitHub forks and on our laptops—we use the name *`B`* on "both sides", so that our laptop repository has an `origin/B` for our branch *`B`*, and then we set the upstream of *`B`* to `origin/B`.

This is *so* common that Git will do this by default for many cases.  The one case where Git *won't* do it automatically by default is when *you first create branch `B` on your laptop* and there is no *`B`* over on GitHub yet.  That means there's no `origin/B` on your laptop, and therefore you can't *set* your laptop's `origin/B` as the upstream of your laptop's *`B`*.

#### `git push` and creating a branch name in another repository

To get branch name `test` to exist *on GitHub*, you must tell GitHub to make it.  There are many ways to do that, but typically, you'd first make your new commit `I`, just as you did, and then use `git push`.  The `git push` command is the closest thing Git gets to the opposite of `git fetch`, but there's one key difference.

Instead of a simple:

```
git fetch
```

which figures out that there's only one place to go, namely `origin`, and goes there and gets *all* their branches and commits and updates *all* your remote-tracking names, you must run:

```
git push origin test
```

which tells your Git *call up `origin` and send over any commits I have on my branch `test` that they don't already have*.  Your branch `test` has commits `I`, `H`, `G`, `F`, and so on; they already have `H`, `G`, and so on; so this sends commit `I`.

Then—having sent this one new commit—your Git politely asks their Git: *Please, if it's OK, create or update the name `test` in your repository so that it finds commit `I`, like it does in my repository.*  **If** they obey this polite request—and in this case they will—they say "OK, did that" and your Git now knows they have `test` pointing to commit `I`, so your Git now creates *your own* `origin/test` pointing to commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
            \
             I   <-- test (HEAD), origin/test
```

Now that `origin/test` exists in your laptop repository, you can ask your Git to set that as the upstream of your `test`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/test test
```

for instance.

This, too, is an extremely common thing to want to do, so much so that `git push` has a flag for it:

```
git push -u origin test
```

means *run `git push origin test`, and if that succeeds, run the corresponding set-upstream-to operation too*.  You generally do this exactly once after creating a new branch (and maybe committing to it, or not; this part is up to you) and *now* your (local) branch name has a remote-tracking name and *they*—in this case GitHub—have a branch of the same name pointing to the same commit and that's why you have the remote-tracking name, and life is good.

Should you *add new commits* to your `test`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
            \
             I   <-- origin/test
              \
               J--K   <-- test (HEAD)
```

you can run `git push` with no options at all, and your Git will now use the upstream setting to invoke `git push origin test` (Git knows to take the `origin/` off here, when calling up `origin` like this) and send them commits `J-K` and politely ask them to set *their* `test` to point to `K`.

This kind of polite request generally succeeds when:

- there are no access controls over at GitHub to prohibit it—note that access controls are a *GitHub* feature, not part of base Git; *and*
- you're merely *adding commits on* to the branch.

Here, commits `J-K` add on to commit `I`, so they will *accept* the polite request, and you'll end up with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
            \
             I--J--K   <-- test (HEAD), origin/test
```

in your laptop repository.

Should you decide that commit `I` is *bad* in some way, you can "poke it out of the way" by making a new commit `J` that points, not to commit `I`, but directly to commit `H`:

```
             J   <-- test (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
            \
             I   <-- origin/test
```

If you now run `git push` or `git push origin test`, your Git sends them commit `J` and asks—politely—if they'll set *their* `test` (reflected in your `origin/test`) to point to `J`.  But this time they will say *no!*  They will say, in effect, *If I do that I'll lose my ability to find commit `I`*.

This, of course, is exactly what you *want*.  Commit `I` is *bad* and you *want them to lose it*, but they don't *understand* that.  You have to tell their Git: *Yes, I know this will lose commit `I`, do it anyway!*  To do that, you must use a more forceful kind of `git push`.  We'll stop here, though, and leave that for other SO questions (already asked and answered!).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response, I really appreciate it, I will go through it all properly and give an adequate response as soon as I can. It clearly took some time for you to prepare so thank you again

Comment: Hi, just to let you know I went through your description a few times and it was very helpful, it really helped me to understand the theory behind what I'm doing, so thanks.